# Dockerfile - /usr/bin/bash: exec: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, docker

I'm just starting out with building containers and have run into this odd issue. The above error comes up when I try to setup apache2 in a container. My ENTRYPOINT and CMD are as follows

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/bash"]
CMD ["exec", "/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
#CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

The commented out CMD part works without any issues. Besides this, I've tried running bash with exec as an option before apachectl and also tried adding exec in the ENTRYPOINT itself

Other than this, I have also tried writing an entrypoint script which does the same thing and the script as follows and it seems to work without any issues.

```
#! /bin/bash

exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND
```

Why is my exec not found in these cases?

Comment: um, that `exec` seems superfluous even when run in bash. It's *not* run in bash – why do you think it would?

Comment: I'm under the impression that when you specify and entrypoint and a cmd, the entrypoint gets run with the cmd array as it's options. Is that not the case ?  
I see that calling apachectl directly would give the same result as calling it with exec. (I was/am trying to see how I can pass SIGTERM to apache2 correctly so that docker doesn't need to send SIGKILL to stop the container but all the above methods doesn't seem to help and I needed to run the container with --init option for apache to respond correctly to SIGTERM)

Comment: you're using the "exec form as default parameters to `ENTRYPOINT`"  from https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd . But `/usr/bin/bash exec` doesn't work, because `exec` is not a shell script file that can be executed. Again, it's not clear why you'd want `exec` at all in this context, but if you really need it, you'd need to use the "shell form" from the documentation, i.e., without the `[` , `]`.

Comment: `/usr/bin/bash` and `/bin/bash` are two different paths.

Comment: @choroba true, but not a problem on modern linuxes, and not the problem at hand here.

Comment: What base Docker image is this running on?

Comment: aah, that makes sense. That being said, I've tried both `CMD /usr/bin/bash exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND` and `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/bash"]
CMD exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND` and still doesn't run(exits with code 126). I was trying to find a way to get apache to termiate gracefully and one of the ideas that I thought to achieve it was by making it run as pid 1 instead of bash running as pid 1(both cases didn't work and I ended up running with --init option to get tini as pid 1 after which apache seems to terminate gracefully)

I'm using the debian:stable as the base image.